# Show a div after running jquery .each() not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a select all script with custom checkboxs and what is happening is that the result number will update however it shows the count up because each checkbox submits the form to get the accurate result number. however when doing the select all which will initiate the click event it shows the number progressing and i want it to only show once the .each event is done. with the current code it will not run the second function to show the div again here is my code for it any help would be great:

```
$('.select_all').live('click',function(){
    $('#psf_search_results_number').hide();
    $('.psf_grp_content input[name="type[]"]').each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
    return false;
},function(){
    $('#psf_search_results_number').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do (but i'm mind reading beacuse it's not really clear to me what your problem is):

```
$('.select_all').live('click',function(){
    $('#psf_search_results_number').hide();
    $('.psf_grp_content input[name="type[]"]').each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
    $('#psf_search_results_number').show();
    return false;
});
```

you can't pass two function to `live()` , if you want to execute `show()` after the `each()` just put it after it

Answer (score 2):

First off, `.live()` has been deprecated and you should be using `.delegate()` (pre-jQuery 1.7) or `.on()` (for jQuery 1.7+).

Second, `.live()` doesn't take two function arguments so it's a no wonder the second one is never called.

If you just want the second function called after the `.each()` loop is done, you can do it this way using `.on()`:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.select_all', function(){
    $('#psf_search_results_number').hide();
    $('.psf_grp_content input[name="type[]"]').each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
    $('#psf_search_results_number').show();
    return false;
});
```

If we could see your HTML, a parent object that is common to all `.select_all` elements would be better than using `document.body`, but it will work as I've' shown it.

Comment: took care of the parent however it does exactly the same thing it was doing before if you look at: http://50.28.19.26/ and click on start search in the middle of the document and popup with come up at which point click on select all under type and look at the results number on the right side and you will see what i am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

```
.live( events, data, handler )
```

**events**   A string containing a JavaScript event type, such as "click" or "keydown." As of jQuery 1.4 the string can contain multiple, space-separated event types or custom event names.

**data**  A map of data that will be passed to the event handler.

**handler**  A function to execute at the time the event is triggered.

`.live()` doesn't take two function arguments